# Use Parallel.ForEach or fill List<Task> by foreach

Tags: c#, multithreading, foreach

I am trying to use multi-threading. I want to run a list of `Task`.there is two choice for me,  I write two code like below:

```
 List<Task> taskList=new List<Task>();
        foreach (var item in itemList)
        {
            taskList.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(()=> DoTasks(item,new Random().Next(15,40))));
        }
        Task.WaitAll(taskList.ToArray());
        Console.WriteLine("All Tasks Done!");
```

And this:

```
 Parallel.ForEach(itemList, item => DoTasks(item, new Random().Next(15, 40)));
        Console.WriteLine("All Tasks Done!");
```

My questions:
Which is better in performance?
Does `Parallel.ForEach` have a `ThreadPool` for manage opened tasks?
Is there any way to this better?

Comment: This entirely depends on what the tasks are doing, there are many applications where running the parallel for-each is just not appropriate so please provide a bit more info explaining what you are trying to accomplish to receive the best answer.

Comment: @Dmitry this is just example code however I edit question.

Comment: [race your horses](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)

Comment: @Kodaloid Supose that DoTasks is a method that try to send one SMS. and itemList.Count=320000

Comment: IMHO the second one is definitely better. Because they both perform the same, and the first one is overcomplicated and clumsy. That's why they developed the Parallel.ForEach, don't you think? :-)

Comment: If that is the case then I would personally steer clear of the parallel for each as you will likely find system resources get utilized far more without any net gain in speed benefit, that functionality has specific use cases and from experience I can assure you that stream requests is not one of it's strong suits.

Comment: `320000` (!) `Task`s? I suggest using `BlockingCollection` as `taskList` (see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312(v=vs.110).aspx) and Producer/Consumer pattern: producer(s) put SMS into the blocking collection and cosumers (several tasks) send these SMS

Comment: @AlKepp `Parallel.ForEach` tries to run a single task for each core of CPU. Good for cpu bounded tasks. But If your tasks are more related with IO(web/DB/disk requests) and idle most of the time, then you may want to start more tasks then your cores). Just a thought....

Comment: @L.B If your work is IO bound, not CPU bound, *you shouldn't be using multiple threads in the first place*.  Not only is it not appropriate to create *even more* threads, you shouldn't even be creating as many as you have cores.  You don't need *any*.  Creating (or allocating from the thread pool) a ton of threads just to have them spend all of their time sitting around doing nothing isn't productive; it's just a waste of system resources.

Comment: Time for send SMS is 0.5s. and for 32000 SMS take 44 Hours! I want to send these so faster by Parallel

Comment: @Servy Read my comment again. I never mentioned "thread", I used the word "task"

Comment: @L.B You can only ever "start" a Task that represents the execution of CPU bound work in a thread, and the whole comment is referring to the scheduling of work on the CPU, so if you're not referring to Tasks representing work done by a thread, and instead were intending to refer to tasks repesenting IO bound work that don't involve the use of any threads at all, then it still doesn't make sense.  You also say that `Parallel.ForEach` runs tasks, which just isn't true, it doesn't use tasks at all, it just uses threads, so the whole thing just doesn't make sense in that light.

Comment: @Servy `Task.WhenAll(new[N]{httpClient.GetStringAsync()......})` doesn't involve a thread, Read my comment in this context... what is the problem in starting 100 web requests? (ignoring NW bandwidth and flooding the server etc)

Comment: I don't know why you're worried about which of these two approaches is faster. The overhead to create threads is enormous. You should worry about whether or not the task is significantly more time consuming than the creation of the threads.

Answer (score 0):

Parallel.Foreach is better choice. It will reuse current thread to execute DoTasks, so total number of threads will be less than in the first case. In addition, it will start execution immediately while in the case with foreach there could be some delay between a moment when you created tasks and a moment when scheduler will run first Task.